# Return JSON with id in front

Tags: php, angularjs, json, api

How do I pull out the `id` in front of each JSON return object from my API?

Current:

```
{  
   "1516":{  
      "id":"1516",
      "firstname":"Aluno",
      "lastname":"Teste",
      "email":"teste@gmail.com",
      "dlastaccess":"28-10-2016",
      "coursename":"Curso Demonstra\u00e7\u00e3o"
   }
}
```

How do I want to leave:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1516",
      "firstname":"Aluno",
      "lastname":"Teste",
      "email":"teste@gmail.com",
      "dlastaccess":"28-10-2016",
      "coursename":"Curso Demonstra\u00e7\u00e3o"
   }
]
```

I'm trying to do this because my checklist-model does not work the way the JSON return comes, so I can not check all the checkboxes.

API:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
$json = '{"1516":{"id":"1516","firstname":"Aluno","lastname":"Teste","email":"teste@gmail.com","dlastaccess":"28-10-2016","coursename":"Curso Demonstra\u00e7\u00e3o"}}';

$values = json_decode($json, true);

$values = array_values($values);

echo json_encode($values);
```

returns:

```
[{"id":"1516","firstname":"Aluno","lastname":"Teste","email":"teste@gmail.com","dlastaccess":"28-10-2016","coursename":"Curso Demonstra\u00e7\u00e3o"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your $result is an array (or object) of this type:

> $result[id] = array(sql retrieved);

Because sql returns you a list of results, even if the result is unique. Imagine that your query returned two results, how could you separate them?

Try:

> echo json_encode($result[$cursoid])

or

> echo json_encode($result->$cursoid)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cursoid = $_GET['idcurso'];

$sql = 'SELECT
user2.id AS ID,
user2.firstname AS Firstname,
user2.lastname AS Lastname,
user2.email AS Email,
IF (user2.lastaccess = 0,"nunca", 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(user2.1astaccess),"%d-96m-W")) AS dLastAccess ,c.fullname AS Coursename
FROM mdl_user_enrolments AS ue
JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
JOIN mdl_user AS user2 ON user2 .id = ue.userid
WHERE (SELECT timeaccess FROM mdl_user_lastaccess WHERE userid=user2.id AND courseid=c.id) IS NULL and c.id = ?';

$params = array($cursoid);

$result = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);
echo json_encode(array_values($result)); // You can easily access array values without their keys by array_values(array $param) function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_values, default php function

```
$values = $DB->get_records_sql( $sql, $params );
$result = array_values( $values );
return json_encode($result);
```